# How to Edit the CSS File of the Installed Plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

**I want to edit the CSS File of the Installed Plugin in Wordpress for some customization of the design.**

**I tried to found the css file of the installed plugin by navigating through Plugins --> Installed Plugin** -->Editor. In that I did'nt find the css file of that plugin instead I found only the .php extension files for the installed plugin.

So i **"installed Custom CSS Editor Plugin"** and i tried to override the some of the CSS property of that plugin in the custom CSS Editor but the changes i made in that custom css is not reflecting on the web page but i tried to edit the css using inspect element on the browser is working correctly.

And then i tried the same CSS property on the **Style.css**  file for the installed **Theme**, it is also not reflecting on the web page.

could anyone help me to understand **how to edit the css properties of the installed plugin?**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying on local or server?

Comment: Did you override the properties with `!important`? It's not the most desired way to style something, but sometimes it's the only way to do it...

Comment: No I'm not using the local server it is on the web hosting server ,i tried to override using " !important" but is also not working.i want to find the css file of the installed plugin.where to find the css file for the plugin. while using the inspect element in the browser i found the css file for the concern plugin but can't find the css file for the installed plugin.

Comment: Also be careful to override style correctly. Your css must be the same as theirs (with the following id's and classes) so that you could override it. Unless their has `!important`, you should be able to override it. The file should be in the plugin folder. Log in with ftp and go to `/plugins` folder and find it there...

Comment: you need to find [wp_add_inline_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style)  or `wp_enqueue_scripts`  or `wp_register_style()` or `wp_enqueue_style()` in your plugin folder first to locate css tag or file then you need to extract exact css rule where css properties are defined from browser inspector and then need to put it in the end in your theme style.css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to edit css file of a plugin is you need to have access to cpanel or ftp of that site. wp-content -> plugins -> open the specific plugin folder. You will find css folder or file. you can change in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate the file with the css rules in your theme folder, the rules could also be embedded in the head.php files using a `<style>` tag.
Try to locate all the .css files within your theme folder and rename them to something like Style.css.old or any other file name, then just find the file that breaks your page when renamed. You should also take a look at the generated html and make sure that no `<style>` tags are used.